# Wiill banks refuse my application for a current account if I don't pay a salary in?

Tags: united-kingdom, banking, bank-account, online-banking, checking-account

I want to apply for a second current account to put funds into and also for some perks that they have (I don't want any interest due to religious reasons). But my salary will not be going into this account. I've seen some bank accounts that offer free no-minimum-funding current accounts (in other words they don't have a minimum you have to pay in), but what are the chances that these banks won't simply just refuse me an account? I'm asking because I would rather not apply for many different accounts without knowing my chances.

Thank you so much.

Comment: Every bank I’ve used explicitly lists such requirements, so you can find out their expectations before attempting to open an account. If you can direct a small percentage of your salary to the new account, you may get better terms and/or a wider selection of banks/account types.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid any accounts that have specific perks but require you to pay in a regular salary.  Even then, you can sometimes work around it by setting up a standing order from your main account to pay in the minimum amount every month.  They rarely require that the money going in is a salary.

Other than that, you don't actually have to tell them that you won't be paying any salary in, when you apply for the account.